# rvm rails install takes too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I use `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`
to quicky install the latest ruby and rails.
But it takes nearly ten minutes for the command to complete and a lot of time is spent generating ri/rdoc documentation.
Is there a way to skip the while documentation generation.

Answer (score 0):

When a gem gets installed - as is the case when you're installing the Rails gem and all of its dependent gems - all documentation will get generated, as you know. You can set the defaults for installing gems via a `.gemrc` file in your home directory, add:

```
gem: --no-document
```

to the file `~/.gemrc`. And then all of your gems will skip doc generation.